# Show that $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt2]=\{a+b\sqrt2 \mid a,b \in \Bbb Z\}$ is the smallest subring of $\Bbb R$ that contains the integers and $\sqrt2$.

Tags: ring-theory, solution-verification

> Show that $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt2]=\{a+b\sqrt2 \mid a,b \in \Bbb Z\}$ is the smallest subring of $\Bbb R$ that contains the integers and $\sqrt2$.

Can I show this by taking any subring of the reals that contains $\Bbb Z$ and $\sqrt2$ and showing that $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt2]$ is a subset of this ring?

If I let $R$ be a subring of $\Bbb R$ such that $\Bbb Z \subseteq R$ and $\sqrt2 \in R$, then as $R$ is closed under multiplication and addition it contains elements of the form $a + b\sqrt2$, where $a,b \in \Bbb Z$.

I don't think I'm arguing very rigorously here so is there something else I could consider?

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument you gave is fine, and sufficiently rigorous, as far as it goes.

However your proof leaves out an important step, which is easy enough to fill in: You must also show that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$ is, itself, a subring of $\mathbb R$. Without doing that, there is a counterexample: $\mathbb Z \cup \{\sqrt{2}\}$ is also a subset of every subring of the reals that contains $\mathbb Z$ and $\sqrt{2}$, but $\mathbb Z \cup \{\sqrt2\}$ is not a subring of the reals.

Answer (score 1):

What you did is perfectly rigorous: you just proved that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]\subseteq R$ for any subring $R$ of $\mathbb{R}$ containing $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\sqrt{2}$. This is the very definition of "smallest ring".

Comment: YES! I wanted to type something about what is in general the definition of 'smallest ring' because it can be useful for the OP in the future, but this answer does that in a very nice and concise way! +1